# incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'NSInteger' (aka 'int')

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

Using a UISegmentedControl, I am getting the error suggested in the Title for the last line of this code.

```
- (IBAction)segmentAction:(id)sender
{
    //NSLog(@"segmentAction: selected segment = %d", [sender selectedSegmentIndex]);
    NSArray *speeds = @[@1.25, @1.5, @2.0];
    speed = [speeds objectAtIndex:[sender selectedSegmentIndex]];
}
```

The declaration for `speed` is `NSInteger speed;`.

Can you help with the raised issue, please?

Comment: `[speeds objectAtIndex:[sender selectedSegmentIndex]]` is `NSNumber*`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're assigning a `NSNumber *` to a `NSInteger`.

Keep in mind that `NSArray`s store objects and that `@1.25` is a shorthand for `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.25]`

Change it to

```
speed = [[speeds objectAtIndex:[sender selectedSegmentIndex]] integerValue];
```

or with a nicer syntax

```
speed = speeds[sender.selectedSegmentIndex].integerValue;
```

Also I think what you want is `speed` to be a `float`, instead of a `NSInteger`. You cannot assign 1.25, for instance, to a `NSInteger`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `objectAtIndex:` returns an `id`, which cannot be assigned to an `int`, because `@32` would return an `NSNumber`, which is an objective-c type. Use this

```
[[speeds objectAtIndex:[sender selectedSegmentIndex]] integerValue]
```

or `floatValue`, depending on what you need.